# What's the name/type for the closest match to this siding around today?

Tags: siding

[image: 12 inch oc siding]

I need to match some siding on my house that is a modular home built in 1993.  The best I could come up with is reverse board and batten siding with 12 inch on-centers.  It doesn't feel like wood, nor vinyl.  My guess then is that it is cement?  Unfortunately, I also lost the paper/certificate that shows information on the house such as by who and where it was built.

I've found a few wood-based products online at Lowes and Home depot that seem to match.  However, none of them are in stock in any store or online.  Also, 12" on-center siding doesn't seem to be much available anymore as 6" and 8" seem more popular.  Here is what I've found from [Lowes](http://m.lowes.com/pd/Plytanium-Natural-Rough-Sawn-SYP-Plywood-Untreated-Wood-Siding-Panel-Common-0-59-in-x-48-in-x-96-in-Actual-0-578-in-x-47-875-in-x-95-875-in/3010818) and something similar from Home Depot (I lack the stackexchange reputation to post another link).

Is there a name for this siding so I can better find its availability around town?  If not, does anyone know the name/type of siding that closest matches this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Requests for product recommendations are generally off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I've updated the question to better meet my true intent which was to identify the siding or learn about the name/types of similar siding.

Comment: Can you give us more information on the sideing is it vinyl or cement (hardi plank type) . The area the home is produced in and the model may give more insight to the actual siding you are trying to match. P.S. This looks like a higher end siding and may be expensive or hard to find.

Comment: Thanks Ed.  I've updated the question.  Cement, I think.  And, I don't know where the home was produced or by what entity.

Comment: It looks like a fancy kind of beadboard.  If you have a local place that does millwork, they might be able to help you.  And by that I mean a dedicated place, not someone at one of the Big Blue Box or Big Orange Box stores.